# DNS resolution of ExternalName in Minikube on Mac

Tags: macos, kubernetes, dns, minikube, kube-dns

I'm trying to connect to a postgres container running in docker on my mac, from my minikube setup in virtualbox. But I'm running into dns resolve issues.

I'm running postgres as a container on docker

```
> docker ps                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
a794aca3a6dc        postgres            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 days ago          Up 3 days           0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   postgres
```

On my Mac / VirtualBox / Minikube setup I create a service

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-svc
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: 10.0.2.2
  ports:
    - port: 5432
```

`10.0.2.2` is alias to host interface (found this information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808560/why-do-we-use-10-0-2-2-to-connect-to-local-web-server-instead-of-using-computer/34732276#34732276))

```
> kubectl get service --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       kubernetes                                       ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                  21d
hazelnut      postgres-svc                                     ExternalName   <none>           10.0.2.2      5432/TCP                 27m
kube-system   kube-dns                                         ClusterIP      10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   21d
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard                             ClusterIP      10.108.181.235   <none>        80/TCP                   19d
kube-system   tiller-deploy                                    ClusterIP      10.101.218.56    <none>        44134/TCP                20d
```

(our namespace is `hazelnut`, don't ask:-)

In my deployment, if I connect to 10.0.2.2 directly, it connects to the postgres without issue, but if I try to resolve the hostname of the kubernetes service it doesnt' work.
So it's not a firewall or routing issue, pure dns.

I've tried `postgres-svc.hazelnut.cluster.local`,
`postgres-svc`, `postgres-svc.hazelnut.svc.cluster.local`, `postgres-svc.hazelnut` all resulting in NXDOMAIN

`kubernetes.default` works though.

```
> nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.96.0.1
```

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52356455/kubernetes-externalname-service-not-visible-in-dns) they mention that using kube-dns should solve it, but I'm using it and to no avail

```
> kubectl get svc --namespace=kube-system
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   21d
...
```

Any idea how I can get this to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the [ExternalName service type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) the `externalName` should be FQDN, not an IP address, e.g.

```
kind: Service
...
metadata:
  name: postgres-svc
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: mydb.mytestdomain
```

The host machine should be able to resolve the name of that FQDN. You might add a record into the `/etc/hosts` at the Mac host to achieve that:

```
10.0.0.2    mydb.mytestdomain
```

Actually, coredns uses name resolver configured in the `/etc/resolv.conf` in the Minikube VM. It points to the name resolver in the VirtualBox NAT Network (10.0.2.3). In turn, VirtualBox relies on the host name resolving mechanism that looks through the local `/etc/hosts` file.

Tested for: 
MacOS 10.14.3, 
VBox 6.0.10, 
kubernetes 1.15.0, 
minikube 1.2.0, 
coredns