# Cannot export a IP in minikube and haproxy loadBalancer

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, minikube, haproxy-ingress

I'm newer with kubernetes. I've installed minikube v1.5.2 in a virtualbox VM (ubuntu 19.10). I want to create a web server that I can access from the host and guest. However, I can't access it or expose an IP. Could you help me?

I've already enabled the ingress addons.

When I try list the ingress object there is no external IP and I recive this error message from ingress controller deployment:

```
2019/11/10 15:41:04 controller-haproxy.go:147 service does not exists
2019/11/10 15:41:09 controller.go:333: service  does not exists
2019/11/10 15:41:09 controller-haproxy.go:147 service  does not exists
2019/11/10 15:41:14 controller.go:333: service  does not exists
2019/11/10 15:41:14 controller-haproxy.go:147 service  does not exists
```

This is my code: https://pastebin.com/ysMPtyuV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minikube introduced supporting of `LoadBalancer` via [minikube tunnel](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tasks/loadbalancer/).

When you are not using `$ sudo minikube tunnel` your LB service will be in `pending` state whole time.

You need to open another SSH window and run `$ sudo minikube tunnel`. You will receive output in one SSH like:

```
$ sudo minikube tunnel
Status:
        machine: minikube
        pid: 11549
        route: 10.96.0.0/12 -> 10.132.15.208
        minikube: Running
        services: [haproxy-ingress]
    errors: 
                minikube: no errors
                router: no errors
                loadbalancer emulator: no errors
```

In the second SSH you will be able to check that LB service obtain IP address.

```
minikube:~$ kubectl get svc -w
NAME              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
app               ClusterIP      10.105.136.11   <none>        80/TCP         68s
haproxy-ingress   LoadBalancer   10.111.24.111   <pending>     80:31187/TCP   68s
kubernetes        ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        11d
haproxy-ingress   LoadBalancer   10.111.24.111   10.111.24.111   80:31187/TCP   80s
```

Please keep in mind that `minikube tunnel` session must be opened whole the time otherwise your LB will stop getting IP address.

You can check similar case with [Kong using minikube LB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58270291/11148139).

Let me know if that helped you.

Comment: Hi @PjoterS.Thank you for your help. I tried it but it still not working. Now I have an External-IP but I cant access my pods from there. This is what I did: curl -I -H 'Host: web-aap.local' 'http://10.102.220.80' (ERROR: 503 Server Unavailable) e curl -I -H 'Host: web-aap.local' 'http://10.102.220.80:31993' (No route to host). How can I access it?

Comment: Please provide output of `$ minikube service haproxy-ingress` and when you will run  `$ curl -i <output of previous command URL address>` ? Also what `--vm-driver` are you using?

Comment: Hi, PjoterS. Sorry to answer too late. I chose to change to Kubernetes and Metallb. Your solution changed the External IP, so I will mark it as the correct answer. Thx!!